# Mongoose get object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I am trying to get users from my mongodb database, Here is what part of my json looks like

```json
"hpCDaKverVWEYukAhAcM8NU6SP73" : {
      "admin" : false,
      "booksBorrowed" : [ {
        "id" : "9780321831552",
        "timeStamp" : 1618881802437
      }, {
        "id" : "9780007204496",
        "timeStamp" : 1618881803678
      }, {
        "id" : "9780316491297",
        "timeStamp" : 1618882675513
      }, {
        "id" : "9780440335160",
        "timeStamp" : 1618882676756
      }, {
        "id" : "9781482287325",
        "timeStamp" : 1618887153684
      } ],
```

I am trying to get the books borrowed array

i tried creating a new schema like this

```js
const BorrowedBook = new Schema({
    id : {type: String, default: ''},
    timeStamp : {type: Number, default: 0},
})
```

then doing this in mongoose.model

```js
booksBorrowed: [BorrowedBook]
```

then I do this in server.js

```js
const User = require('./models/user')
app.get('/api/users', function (req, res) {
    User.find(function (err, users) {
        console.log(users)
    })
})
```

but it just prints this
`booksBorrowed: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `console.dir(users)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, its just `console.log(users)` printing this, since it doesnt print nested lvl objects.

You can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(users))` or `console.dir(users)`.